# Hostname (SNI) missing while using nginx ingress SSL Passtrough to underlying service

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to implement SSL Passtrough with `nginx-ingress-controller`. This is my Ingress Object:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
  labels:
    my-label: example
  name: example
  namespace: example
spec:
  rules:
  - host: '*.example.com'
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: example
          servicePort: 8443
        path: /
```

The `--enable-ssl-passtrough` flag is present in the controller args.

When request is coming trough ingress controller to my underlying service I'm trying to parse the SNI to find out what domain was used to find out the certificate I should present, but the service cannot find the SNI and returns this error:

```
{"level":"debug","ts":1592992137.1836417,"msg":"Error getting server name","error":"No hostname"}
```

Does `nginx-ingress-controller` remove the SNI when parsing? Or what may be the reason for such behavior?

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: How are you trying to get the SNI from the ingress? What is your cloud provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted nginx-ingress developers directly and I got information that the reason this is not working is the wildcard domain, which is not supported by `nginx-ingress`.

Everything else is configured correctly and when changing `*.example.com` into something specific (e.g. `whatever.example.com`) it works correctly.